# MYSQL count in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have data in database like this

```
id  class  gender
1     A      F
2     B      F
3     A      M
4     A      F
5     A      M
6     B      M
7     A      F
```

From this data I want to make select statement to produce report like this

```
_________________________
        Gender
class   M    F     Total
_________________________
A       2    3       5
B       1    1       2
_________________________
TOTAL   3    4       7
```

How can I make that select statement ?

Comment: the primary purpose of having a database server is to store the data, not for generating report, the counts are possible but by formatting makes it difficult, why not do it on your application level?

Comment: Thanks, now I get some idea. I will count the total in the application. But how can I get total gender based on class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the following example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaaec/6/0)

```
SELECT class,
      SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `M`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `F`,
      COUNT(1) Total
FROM Table1
GROUP BY class
```

Answer (score 2):

To get totals for each gender:

```
SELECT class, gender, COUNT(*) as gender_count
FROM Gender
GROUP BY class, gender;
```

To get total:

```
SELECT class, COUNT(*) as total_count
FROM Gender
GROUP BY class;
```